# Calculate Percent Change of a PHP variable every 24 Hours

Tags: php

A Variable in Changing every 1 Minute in PHP. How do I calculate its Percent Change every 24 Hours? I know it is very easy if we have 2 variables but how should I code if we have just one variable that changes every minute and we need to calculate its percent change and echo it out?

Comment: A cron / scheduled job perhaps? Not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: If it's "easy with two variables", then you already know how to do what you need, surely!??

Comment: I'd suggest adding another variable, then use your very easy solution to monitor both.  The new variable won't change because we just made that, so it's a secret, and you then know that any change must be down to the first variable.

Answer (score 0):

save the daily starting value of that variable in a DB table. Then with a daily cron job, check how much that value changed in the last day and calculate the percent change, save that in the table as well, and save the current value again for the next day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which method you will want to use to save this data on every change.

if you prefer to use Database then it can make your life easier. First record the variable 1 into a database table with a TIMESTAMP column. Then run a SQL query every 24hours to calculate percentage.

If you have a slow performance due to Database Connection every minute you can write this variable 1 into a TXT file with JSON data. Every 24 hours you can pull this data and do your maths with it.

if you need automated echo every 24 hours, you can use either Cron job or Timmer.